# Error while fetching data from WhereScape red

Tags: sql-server

I have created on load table. However, while viewing data I'm getting error below:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Invalid object name 'LOAD_TAL_Tablename'

May I know what is the problem? How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Very old topic, but still worth to answer.

The reason is invalid syntax, as mentioned above. I received the same error and then investigated in logs that although I am loading data between different databases, Wherescape did not add reference to appropriate source database in generated SQL code. So, by default, it was referring to target database when looking for source table.

To fix this, see below steps:

1. Find your soruce connection and open it's **Properties**
2. On **Properties** tab, in **Source System** section make sure that the field **Database ID** is filled in with name of your database. If not - put it there
3. Try to load tables and look at SQL used to load the table in logs. Make sure your reference to source table is three-part (this time it should point to correct database).

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the object exists (natch!) and more specifically what schema it is located in. By default RED will expect to see it in the dbo schema and I have seen in the past that if you are using AD and groups for authentication/authorisation objects may get created under the default schema of the automatically-created user (if that is the case, delete them manually in SSMS and set the Default Schema mapping for the user to "dbo")

Of course, you have actually /created/ the table haven't you? Just defining it in RED will only create tyhe meta data definition. Make sure you have right-clicked and chosen Create/ReCreate etc... (though to be fair if this is where you are stuck ...)

HTH,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code that you used to create the table as well as the code you are running when you get the error. It just sounds like a syntax issue.